# How to get telerik radwindow title from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

How to show the **RadWindow** title from codebehind.

asp.x

```
 <telerik:RadWindow ID="radcalllog" runat="server" model="true" Animation="none" Style="z-index: 100000;"
    VisibleOnPageLoad="false" Skin="Windows7" Width="600px" KeepInScreenBounds="true"
    ReloadOnShow="false" Height="450px" EnableShadow="false" Modal="true" VisibleStatusbar="false"
    VisibleTitlebar="true" Behaviors="Close,Pin" Title="CALL LOG" EnableViewState="true"></telerik:RadWindow>
```

Comment: Refer this site http://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamically-setting-the-title-of-a-radwindow

Answer (score 0):

To show a RadWindow from the code-behind, follow this: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/opening-from-the-server
Essentially, register a script:

```
string script = "function f(){$find(\"" + RadWindow1.ClientID + "\").show(); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", script, true);
```

The Title property will be in effect if the content page you load in it does not have its own `<title>` set. If it has, RadWindow will behave like a browser window and display that title in its Titlebar. To avoid that, use the OnClientPageLoad event to set your own title back. Note that you will need a custom attribute for that because it will be overriden on the client:

```
        <telerik:RadWindow runat="server" ID="rw1" myServerTitle="My title" NavigateUrl="some-page.aspx" OnClientPageLoad="OnClientPageLoad"></telerik:RadWindow>
        <script>
            function OnClientPageLoad(sender, args) {
                sender.set_title(sender.get_element().getAttribute("myServerTitle"));
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it from server side you may want to try this line of code:

```
string title=radcalllog.Title;
```

Best regards,

Diane